# if(condition fails in jascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have following code which is working in localhost in windows. But in the server same code fails.

It's the `if` condition which is not getting executed write even if `data==found;`  I checked the returned data value which is `found` but cant figure out why the code is not executing properly

```
function checkAvailability() {
  $("#loaderIcon").show();
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "ajaxcheck.php",
    data:'tran_id='+$("#tran_id").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
      //var x=data;
      $("#loaderIcon").hide();
      //console.log((data=="found"));
      if(data=="found")
      {
        $("#singlebutton").prop('disabled', false);
        console.log("fail");
        $("#tran_id-status").html("Found");
      }
      else
      {
        console.log(data);
        $("#singlebutton").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#tran_id-status").html("");  
        console.log("ss");
      }
    },
    error:function (){}
  });
}
```

Here is ajaxcheck.php

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$space=" ";

if(!empty($_POST["tran_id"])) {
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM bank WHERE tran_id ='" . $space.$_POST["tran_id"] . "'");
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
  $user_count = $row[0];
  if($user_count>0) {
     // echo "<span class='status-not-available' id=\"stat\"name=\"stat\" value=\"ok\"> Transaction Details Found.</span>";
    echo"found";
  }else{
      //echo "<span class='status-available' id = \"stat\" name =\"stat\"value=\"not\"> (Enter Valid transaction id to submit)</span>";
      echo"notfound";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Yep, x is never defined because your code is commented.......unless you meant something else entirely...

Comment: @chris85 changed that in question typo. problem was with if(data=="found"),

Comment: What did `console.log((data=="found"))` yield? Is there any whitespace before or after the `found`?

Comment: @chris85     false,no there is no  white space

Comment: Your comment in the answer below suggests there are new lines. Try `if(data.trim()=="found")`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: @chris85  \r\n are added can't figure out why ? added the phpcode

Comment: There's no empty lines after `?>`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82249/discussion-between-chris85-and-xax).

Comment: @chris85 yes there was.

Comment: That's the issue. I posted both options to resolve the issue as an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your `data` variable is coming back with a new line character. There are two solutions to this 1. trim the returned value. 2. figure out why the php is serving a new line.

Solution 1:

```
if(data.trim()=="found")
```

This uses the JS trim function, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim.

Solution 2:

Try removing the `?>` from the end of your PHP file (the PHP file will still be valid). This way if there are extra lines after it they won't be served as output and the JS wont receive them.

From the manual:

> If a file is pure PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the script.