# if statement in Ajax callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, authentication

Hi im having a problem refreshing my page when a condition is met in php using ajax, if the php script is successful i want it to reload the page but when it is not then i only want to echo the errors.

The following is the part of my PHP code that returns the 'success' or error message:

```
if ($login) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo '<p>Username and Password does not match</p>';
};
```

This is working as i have tested it separately and the user gets logged in even though ajax

The problem i think comes in the ajax call back with the if statement. 
Here is the my js script that is running the ajax call back.

```js
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function(){

    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();

        data[name] = value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
            if(response == "success") {
                                //location.reload();
                window.location = "index.php";
            } else {
                $('#loginError').html(response);
            };
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

I have tried everything on the net but every time the PHP script is successful it just echo's out the word success rather then redirecting the page or reloading

Comment: You probably have leading or trailing white space characters in your response.

Comment: Try `console.log(response);` before the `if`. See what the actual value is. Might have new lines. Here's an answer to similar thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197638/ifcondition-fails-in-jascript/31197876#31197876

Comment: WOW !! thanks Felix and especially chris85, your advice worked like a charm <3

Answer (score 0):

Thanks chris85 for the perfect advice worked like gold and was able to fix the problem, that was that there was a extra line at the top of my PHP script that I missed and saw it when i used `console.log(response)`, also read the post you linked and it will help with future problems like this for me so thanks again.