# Comparing strings in JQuery not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Alright so here's the situation. I have the following code block in my php file, and for some reason, whenever it comes to check data, it doesn't accept. I've printed out the value of data, and it is indeed "accepted" (without quotes obviously). Am I comparing these wrong somehow? Running basically the exact same code in another section of my website and it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sign").click(function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "loginConfirm.php",
            data: { // Correct
                username: $("#username").val(),
                password: $("#password").val()
            },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                if ($("#username").val() === "") {
                    //Do nothin
                } else if (data === "accepted") {
                    alert("Here");
                    redirectSignIn();

                } else {
                    alert("There");
                    $("#signInTitle").html(data);

                }
            },
            error: function () {}
        });

    });
});
```

EDIT: php code I'm calling in the url below

```
<?php
// The global $_POST variable allows you to access the data sent with the POST method
// To access the data sent with the GET method, you can use $_GET
$username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
$userpassword = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);

require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM loginInfo WHERE userName='" . $username . "' AND password='" . $userpassword . "'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $user_count = $row[0];

    if($user_count>0) 
        echo "accepted";
    else 
        echo "denied";
?>
```

Comment: Maybe, because the first `if` is executing, and the next `else if` will not execute

Comment: Any new lines on `accepted`?

Comment: Nope tried removing the initial if a long time ago. It always goes to the final else. And nope, no new lines.

Comment: Added php code as well

Comment: try using [*.trim*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), there might be whitespace in your response

Comment: Try taking off the `?>`. Also you are open to SQL injections.

Comment: You should validate  `f ($("#username").val() === "")` before making ajax call.

Comment: I'm sure of the input I'm using. It is valid and correct. And yes, I know I'm vulnerable to SQL injections. Security is coming afterwards, and while that certainly isn't best practice, I'm only currently learning how to prevent SQL injections, so it's the only option

Comment: Okay, so if you take off the closing tag did it work?

Comment: Woah! It was the .trim() call. Strange. Had no clue there was whitespace, nor knew how to identify it.Thanks Mritunjay! If you want to post that as the answer, I'll accept it when I can.

Comment: `The closing tag of a PHP block at the end of a file is optional, and in some cases omitting it is helpful when using include or require, so unwanted whitespace will not occur at the end of files,` http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [if(condition fails in jascript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197638/ifcondition-fails-in-jascript)

Answer (score 0):

You cant validate `if ($("#username").val() === "") {` in success function. For that you are suppose to validate it before making Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give some advice here that first you have to validate the inputs of the user if validate then you can call ajax.

and then you not required to check the value of the username in AJAX process.

Like....

```
if($("#username").val() === "" && $("#passoword").val() === "")
{ 
     //AJAX call
}
else
{
    //alert to enter the valid inputs
}
```

hope you get it my concept...