# login with ajax issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, authentication

I am trying to create on-page login.

without ajax it works very well. Here is my login.php;

```
if($_POST)
{
    $username =$_POST["username"];
    $password =$_POST["password"];
    $query  = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username' && password='$password'",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ( $say = $query -> rowCount() ){
        if( $say > 0 ){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['session']=true;
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;
            $_SESSION['password']=$password;

            echo "ok";

        }else{
            echo "Couldn't login.";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Wrong username or password.";
    }
}
```

Anyway, here is my java script code;

```
            $(function(){
             $("#loginbutton").click(function(){
                var username = $("#username").val();
                var password = $("#password").val();
                if(username != "" && password != ""){
                    $.ajax("login.php",{
                        type : "POST",
                        data : "username="+username+"&password="+password,
                        success : function(data){
                            if(data == "ok"){
                                                    $("#message").html(data);
                            }else{
                                $("#fail").fadeIn();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
             });
            });
```

Even though I put correct login information (when I get "ok" response from login.php, it always outputs  `$("#fail").fadeIn();` . instead of `$("#message").html(data);` I couldn't figure out where I am mistaken.

and here is login form:

```
    <div id="login">    

       <form action="" onsubmit="return false;" method="post">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off"><br>

            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"><br> 

            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="loginbutton" value="Login">

       </form>

            <div id="message">  </div>
            <div id="fail" style="display: none;">failed.</div> 

    </div>
```

Comment: Check if `data` has whitespace before/after it. Also you are open to SQL injections with this code. If data does have whitespace see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197638/ifcondition-fails-in-jascript/31197876#31197876

Comment: Not your current issue..... but you also shouldn't store passwords in plain text.

Comment: @chris85, seems like that was my problem. Thank you. By the way as far as I know, when I use PDO instead of mysql it's safe for SQL injections. Could you give me some clue how to start fixing it?

Comment: PDO by itself is no safer from SQL injections, you need to use prepared statements. If that answer did help you please give it an upvote. Prepared statements can be viewed here, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php. The point of prepared statements is to separate user input from the SQL; that is how injections occur. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1:_Prepared_Statements_.28Parameterized_Queries.29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using type as `post`, but sending parameters as `get`.Change your ajax like this,

```
$.ajax("login.php",{
    type : "POST",
    data : {username:username,password:password},// only this line is changed.
    success : function(data){
        if(data == "ok"){
            $("#message").html(data);
       }else{
           $("#fail").fadeIn();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: if credentials is correct, what is ajax call returning??

Comment: Ajax returns `ok` per OPs question; `when I get "ok" response from login.php`.

Comment: @Lukasz try using `if(data === "ok"){`

Comment: thanks @NiranjanNRaju, I tried with your code and it's works very well.

Comment: @Lukasz If answer was helpful, consider accepting it.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Bhai. +1 From my side too.

Comment: @NanaPartykar Thank u:)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example of using post with JQuery AJAX.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $.post("login.php", {username:username, password:password}, function(data){
 if(data == 'ok'){
     $("#message").html(data);
 }else{
       alert(data);//alert the data you receive. It alerts you if there is any error in php file.
       $("#fail").fadeIn();
 }
});
});
```

Hope that was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, debug your code like this:
1) On button click you will put alert function inside javascript code. if it is working then move second step.

2) use alert function to print username and password if it comes inside your javascript code and correct as you put into input fields then move third step.

3) use serialize method in javascript.

I hope its help you to get your solution.