# php don't show alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with the following code. According to him if in the place on username and we will enter data which are missing in the database on the password should show it oneself alert with information. Unfortunately if I will enter wrong data modal is disappearing and alert isn't being shown. 
I will be grateful for help.

```
<script> $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#login_button').click(function(){  
       var username = $('#username').val();  
       var password = $('#password').val();  
       if(username != '' && password != '')  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"action.php",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data: {username:username, password:password},  
                 success:function(data)  
                 {  
                      //alert(data);  
                      if(data == 'No')  
                      {  
                           alert("Wrong Data");  
                      }  
                      else  
                      {  
                           $('#loginModal').hide();  
                           location.reload();  
                      }  
                 }  
            });  
       }  
       else  
       {  
            alert("Both Fields are required");  
       }  
  });  
  $('#logout').click(function(){  
       var action = "logout";  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"action.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{action:action},  
            success:function()  
            {  
                 location.reload();  
            }  
       });  
  });   });
```

AND Action.php

```
 <?php  
 session_start();  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");  
 if(isset($_POST["username"]))  
 {  
      $query = "  
      SELECT * FROM admin_login  
      WHERE admin_name = '".$_POST["username"]."'  
      AND admin_password = '".$_POST["password"]."'  
      ";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
      {  
           $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];  
           echo 'Yes';  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           echo 'No';  
      }  
 }  
 if(isset($_POST["action"]))  
 {  
      unset($_SESSION["username"]);  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: what shows console.log(data)?  what do you get back in network tab?

Comment: _AND_: your sql is vulnerable to sql injection -> use prepared statements. 2.) don't save plain passwords. user password_hash()

Comment: add return false below alert syntax line. as well as in the last line in click code block.

Comment: The trailing whitespace in the PHP makes your `data`  = `No `, dont use the `else` for success... or use `trim` on the data, or `exit` instead of `echo` so it dies after output. Also see notes above about SQL injections and hashing those should be fixed in the future as welll.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if(condition fails in jascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197638/ifcondition-fails-in-jascript)

Comment: In alert shown of variable date agree: if data agrees is returning "Yes" and if not it is returning "No" but it isn't known why even if the Date is "No" code is entering at once to else although the condition agrees